# Why do c++ instances automatically call constructor and destructor when called via Objective-c classes?

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I have a question:

I don't explicitly "`new`" and "`delete`" my C++ instance, but it automatically calls "`new`" and "`delete`" when the objective-c class init. Any idea?

```
class myCppTestClass
{
public:
    myCppTestClass()
    {
        NSLog(@"MyCpp constructor");
    }

    ~myCppTestClass()
    {
        NSLog(@"MyCpp destructor");
    }
};



@interface MyTestClass : NSObject
{
    myCppTestClass myCppInstance;
}

@end


@implementation MyTestClass


@end
```

And I call it like this:

```
NSLog(@"Create an object.");
MyTestClass *objcObject = [[MyTestClass alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Object created");
[objcObject release];
objcObject = nil;
NSLog(@"Object released.");
```

Then I run it, the log is like this:

```
2012-11-16 12:01:18.747 iOSVersion[87248:f803] Create an object. 
2012-11-16 12:01:18.749 iOSVersion[87248:f803] MyCpp constructor
2012-11-16 12:01:18.750 iOSVersion[87248:f803] Object created
2012-11-16 12:01:18.751 iOSVersion[87248:f803] MyCpp destructor
2012-11-16 12:01:18.752 iOSVersion[87248:f803] Object released.
```

It's not about Automatic Reference Counnting, because it is closed, any ideas? Thank you so much.

Again, if MyTestClass is like this, the constructor and destructor will not been called:

```
@interface MyTestClass : NSObject
{
    myCppTestClass * myCppInstance;
}
```

and the log:

```
2012-11-16 12:22:38.710 iOSVersion[87428:f803] Create an object.
2012-11-16 12:22:38.711 iOSVersion[87428:f803] Object created
2012-11-16 12:22:38.712 iOSVersion[87428:f803] Object released.
```

Comment: It's just how c++ objects work when they aren't pointers or references.

Comment: You mean `myCppTestClass myCppInstance;` ?

Comment: yes, the variable declaration causes the default constructor to be invoked when the object is allocated, through some runtime wizardry.

Comment: You are so kind, Ross, but my quesion is : if I want to implement this, how should i do? Do it in objc runtime? or Foundation.framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The language does not `new` and `delete` for you, but it calls the constructor and destructor. This is the standard behavior of C++: when you create an object, directly or indirectly, the constructor for the contained object gets called; similarly, when the containing object gets deallocated, the destructors of all contained instances get called as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if my declaration is like this: `myCppTestClass * myCppInstance;`, the  constructor and destructor will not been called.. why??

Comment: @lijinma This is because in this case you do not declare an object: instead, you declare a pointer. Initialization happens automatically only for objects, not for pointers. When you use pointers, you need to call `new` and `delete` manually.

Answer (score 1):

`new` and `delete` in C++ aren't used to create objects, they're used to create objects in a freshly-allocated* area of RAM. `myCppInstance`'s data isn't allocated on the heap, it's actually a part of `MyTestClass`. When your code creates a `MyTestClass` object, it will include an already-constructed `myCppTestClass`.

Similarly, if you create a `myCppTestClass` variable, the data for that class is allocated basically for free on the stack. It's deallocated at the end of the scope where it was declared (even if there's an exception).

With `new` and `delete`, you get a pointer to an object and you are responsible for managing its lifetime. If you're just starting to learn C++, you might want to avoid them entirely. In modern C++, it's best to use `make_shared` instead of `new`, and "never" use `delete`.

* Unless you're using placement new

Comment: Thank you too, Matthew, but if my declaration is like this: myCppTestClass * myCppInstance;, the constructor and destructor will not been called.. I have no clue, why??

Comment: Because in that case, you're not defining a `myCppTestClass` instance, you're defining a variable called `myCppInstance` which is actually a pointer to some (as yet undetermined) `myCppTestClass` object (instance). When you changed the type from `myCppTestClass` to `myCppTestClass*`, you really should've renamed the variable to something like `myCppInstancePointer`. You use `new` to create an object on the heap, and then assign that object's value to your pointer variable.

Comment: s/that object's value/that object's address/